# Create several login/register related to other models in backpack for laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-backpack

According to the backpack documentation I should use Laravel authentication, but will I be able to use the crud, fields, filters and functions to generate Backpack in the user area?
If possible, is there anything special I should know about how to create and organize the files for the user area?

And can I apply it to multiple types of users? For example: Suppliers, customers, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can create CRUDs for your users too, not just for your admins. But in that case you should pay special attention to your queries - you probably don't want your users to have access to all info in the db, only their info. You can customize the query using addClause - you can see more info here - https://backpackforlaravel.com/docs/6.x/crud-api#custom-advanced-queries

> is there anything special I should know about how to create and organize the files for the user area

No. I would create a CrudController like you would if it were an admin. Pay special attention in the request - the authorization part should match your use case. For example instead of checking the user is an admin, you should check the user exists and is logged in.

> And can I apply it to multiple types of users? For example: Suppliers, customers, etc.

Yes, you can. Again, the CRUD doesn't really care about who is logged in. If you:

- change the route to be in a route group with YOUR auth checks;
- change the validation requests to do YOUR auth checks;

Then CRUDs will work. You can even make it work for non-logged-in-users.

Comment: I created the users section and have implemented my own theme with the new backpack options. But in the users section it "inherits" the same thing that is used in the administration area. Can this be changed? That is, at least, if in the administration area the menu is lateral, in the user area the menu is superior (at the top) or in general those configurations that are initially established? And if possible, are there cache problems?